# ios pushwoosh implementation error

Tags: ios, cordova, pushwoosh

i have download the sample of ios pushwoosh-phonegap on my mac and i want to run on the device, but it gave me this error that pushwoosh/pushnotificationmanager.h is not found. What is the problem?
and ther is another problem, when i configure the ios on pushwoosh site, it said that can't generate the certificate. i have the apn certificate on the key, i exported .cer file. also i try to upload the download version of the certificate. same error. should i upload the dev certificate. i use free account , so i canot make auto configuration. any help, and Thx.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange, I've just tried the sample and it worked well.
Do you see Pushwoosh.framework added to your project?

Also the other way is to use Phonegap/Cordova CLI to add the plugin using this guide:
http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/ios/ios-additional-platforms/push-notification-sdk-integration-for-phonegap/

When uploading the certificate make sure you upload APN certificate not your developers certificate. It should come as .p12 (that's export from your keychain) and .cer file.

This guide might help:
http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/ios/ios-configuration-guide/

Comment: plz tell me one thing, is it free or a paying service to send a notification from  a website using the api???